# IPtables Traffic Quota - up and down

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, traffic, quota

I've been trying to set up traffic quotas for users on a shared server and i believe [with my limited knowledge] that iptables --quota and ports which have been selected for each user [--dport] is the way to do this...

iptables -A OUTPUT --dport 1,2,3,4... --quota 123412341234 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT --dport 1,2,3,4... -j DROP

I think something like this would work to limit the traffic [and reset every month] but its only for traffic going out.

- Is there something I could do to combine -A OUTPUT and -A INPUT into one quota?
- Or, is there a different method I could use to achieve the same thing more efficiently?

OS is debian squeeze

Thanks.

Comment: Let me ask you a question first: Do you want the quota to apply to **the sum** of INPUT + OUTPUT?

Comment: yes, if that's possible that would be perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to apply quota to **both** incoming and outgoing, you'd do it like this:

```
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport $PORTNUM_1 -g filter_quota_1
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport $PORTNUM_2 -g filter_quota_2
<other OUTPUT rules for other users>
-A INPUT  -p tcp --dport $PORTNUM_1 -g filter_quota_1
-A INPUT  -p tcp --dport $PORTNUM_2 -g filter_quota_2
<other INPUT rules>
-A filter_quota_1 -m quota --quota $QUOTA_1 -g chain_where_quota_not_reached
-A filter_quota_1 -g chain_where_quota_is_reached
-A filter_quota_2 -m quota --quota $QUOTA_2 -g chain_where_quota_not_reached
-A filter_quota_2 -g chain_where_quota_is_reached
<other filter_quota_N chains>
```

When you want to reset quota #N, you'd do `iptables -F filter_quota_N` and then re-populate `filter_quota_N`.

Since the rules are mostly similar, you really should consider automation with bash (or other scripting language of your choice)

Comment: Thank you so much! - I could simply replace "-g chain_where_quota_is/not_reached" with a simple "-j ACCEPT/DROP" to start with something simple right? - Also what's the reason for "-p tcp", would there be any reason to include udp too?

Comment: @Nick `where_quota_not_reached` can be replaced with ACCEPT. but I suggest having a LOG+DROP pair in `where_quota_is_reached`, so you can easily find out if a user has hit her quota. the `-p tcp` is necessary to use `--dport` and `--sport`. UDP traffic generally is negligible, but if you want to monitor it, too, add similar rules but replacing `-p tcp` with `-p udp`

Comment: Thanks for all your help, can't vote you up though :/

Comment: @Nick heh, no problem, don't lose your sleep over it :) ... glad to be of help :)

Comment: No need to flush the chain and repopulate it ... just zero out the counters and you should be done.